# Why audio duration got changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

I'm building a simple seekbar for an audio, but i have a problem with my seekbar and it's duration. When i trigger rewind funtion in nearly end of seekbar, the duration get changed. I dont know why and i want to fix it. I want to show you video or images to decribe it easily but stackoverflow is not allowed that.

```
  const seekSlider = useRef("");

  const [value,setValue] = useState(0);
  const [duration,setDuration] = useState();

  function convertMinute(x) {
    if (!x) return '0:00';

    let min = Math.floor(x / 60);
    let sec = Math.floor(x % 60);
    if (sec < 10) {
      return `${min}:0${sec}`;
    }
    else {
      return `${min}:${sec}`;
    }
  };
  const clickButton = () => {
    if (button.current.className === "fa-solid fa-play")
    {
      button.current.className = "fa-solid fa-pause";
      myAudio.current.play();
    }
    else 
    {
      button.current.className = "fa-solid fa-play";
      myAudio.current.pause();
    }
  }
  const changeSeek = () => {
    const progess = (myAudio.current.currentTime / myAudio.current.duration *100);
    setValue(progess);
  }
  const rewind = (e) => {
    const seekTime = e.target.value/100 * myAudio.current.duration;
    myAudio.current.currentTime = seekTime;
  }
  const onDurationChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setDuration(convertMinute(e.target.duration));
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <div className='button' onClick={clickButton}>
        <span><i ref={button} className="fa-solid fa-play"></i></span>
      </div>

      <div className='seekBar'>
        <span>{convertMinute(myAudio.current.currentTime)}</span>

        <input type='range' className='seekSlider' min='0' max='100' 
        value={value} step='0.01' ref={seekSlider} onInput={(e) => rewind(e)}/>

        <span>{duration}</span>
      </div>

      <audio ref={myAudio} onTimeUpdate={changeSeek} onDurationChange={(e) => onDurationChangeHandler(e)}>
        <source src={podcast} type="audio/mp3" />
      </audio>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: What is your `rewind` function supposed to achieve (in audio playback)? If you want a song to restart then just set audio position in there as `myAudio.current.currentTime = 0;`  (no need to divide and multiply when rewinding)... PS: If rewind means jump some seconds back then try something like: `myAudio.current.currentTime -= 5; //# jumps back 5 seconds`

Comment: hello, sorry for my English, the rewind function is like I jump from the current time to another time by clicking a point in seek bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `100` is the **width** of your seekbar... Try a logic like this:

```
progess = ( myAudio.current.currentTime / myAudio.current.duration ) * 100;

seekTime = ( myAudio.current.duration / 100 ) * e.target.value;
```